# Pmd error regarding logger

Tags: java, logging, static, pmd

I have this line in my code:

```
private transient final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

I build my project and the pmd check tells me that:

```
The Logger variable declaration does not contain the static and final modifiers.
```

What can I do to fix this? I tried putting the static modifier but it comes up with this error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using it in main make it static

and i would use logger like this

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getSimpleName());
```

Comment: Actually, it should be `private static final Logger LOG = ...`. You do not want anyone to assign a new value to the logger reference.

Comment: Oh thanks, I have been learning java for maybe 2 months now so yeah I'm not very good